# HoughCircles not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I would like to know the radius of the red circle on the dart board (where you can score 50).
I converted to HSV and than defined the red color range.
But when I tried to detect circles on my mask image I didn't get the results what I expected. I tried to play with the attributes but I couldn't find a working combination.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('testImages/testImage3_6.jpg')
if img is None:
    print "There is no image with this name! (maybe typo)"

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img.copy(),img.copy(), mask= mask)

edges = cv2.Canny(mask,1000,1500)

maskSmoothed = cv2.medianBlur(mask,5)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(maskSmoothed,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
                            param1=20,param2=20,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

output = img
cmask = cv2.cvtColor(maskSmoothed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(cmask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cmask,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle

cv2.imshow('win', cmask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoW5w.jpg)

[Image about the detected mask and edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G898G.jpg)

[Detected circles on the mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YKw.jpg)

How could I detect it precisely? I need the radius.

Comment: The opencv implementation won't work for concentric circles.. There are a few tricks to make it work (search in SO)

Comment: How many iterations have you done?

Comment: I don't know this is the first time I'm using this fuction